# Matching a column from a data frame on the columns of another data frame and if they match add a new column

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, matching

I got two big data frames, one (df1) has this structure

```
    V1    V2    V3
1  Chr1  7507 10944
2  Chr1 10944 13170
3  Chr1 13170 20065
4  Chr1 20065 28273
5  Chr1 28273 29960
6  Chr1 29960 36599
7  Chr1 36599 37513
8  Chr1 37513 40360
9  Chr1 40360 48796
10 Chr1 48796 50661
```

The other (df2) has this

```
     V1    V2    V3 V4  V5
1  Chr1  7507  7507  1   1
2  Chr1 10944 10944  1   2
3  Chr1 13170 13170  1  22
4  Chr1 20065 20065  1   3
5  Chr1 28273 28273  1 161
6  Chr1 29960 29960  1  10
7  Chr1 36599 36599  1 604
8  Chr1 37513 37513  1 117
9  Chr1 40360 40360  1   8
10 Chr1 48796 48796  1   3
```

what I'm trying to do is to check if the column V2 or V3 (is the same) of df2 is = or between the range of V2 and V3 of df1 then I want to write the value of V5 of df2 in a new column in df1 if not write 0. the result that i want would be like :

```
Chr1    7507    10944   1
Chr1    10944   13170   2   
Chr1    13170   20065   22  
Chr1    20065   28273   3   
Chr1    28273   29960   161 
Chr1    29960   36599   10  
Chr1    36599   37513   604 
Chr1    37513   40360   117 
Chr1    40360   48796   8
.
.
.
```

Do you know any good way to do this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you need to use `merge`. You can check the example in R help files (`?merge`)

Comment: In your example, all V2 and V3 values of df2 have an exact match in V2 of df1. If this applies to your whole data, then a relatively simple `merge` is appropriate as suggested by @dickoa. If your actual data is different (so that you would need to check ranges), it would be better if you could also edit your sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @beginneR already mentioned in the comments, all `V2` and `V3` values of `df2` have an exact match with `V2` of `df1`. If I interpret your question correctly, this is probably not what you wanted. The following example is what I yhink you are looking for.

Reading the two dataframes:

```
df1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="rn    V1    V2    V3
1  Chr1  7507 10944
2  Chr1 10944 13170
3  Chr1 13170 20065
4  Chr1 20065 28273
5  Chr1 28273 29960
6  Chr1 29960 36599
7  Chr1 36599 37513
8  Chr1 37513 40360
9  Chr1 40360 48796
10 Chr1 48796 50661")

df2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="rn     V1    V2    V3 V4  V5
1  Chr1  7507  7507  1   1
2  Chr1 10944 10944  1   2
3  Chr1 13170 13170  1  22
4  Chr1 20065 20065  1   3
5  Chr1 28273 28273  1 161
6  Chr1 29960 29960  1  10
7  Chr1 36599 36599  1 604
8  Chr1 37513 37513  1 117
9  Chr1 40360 40360  1   8
10 Chr1 48796 48796  1   3")
```

Getting rid of V3 in df2 as it is exactly the same as V2:

```
df2 <- df2[,-4]
```

Making the values in V2 of df2 higher

```
df2$V2 <- df2$V2 + 2000
```

With the `ifelse` function you can assign the values of V5 to a new variable in df1 when the meet the requirements:

```
df1$V4 <- ifelse(df2$V2 >= df1$V2 & df2$V2 <= df1$V3, df2$V5, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Jaap and @beginneR!! based on this i had to modify some elements and i did it! We have to take care some more parameters! so Now the code is like upto <- dim(df1)[1]
for (i in 1:upto) {   
  result <- df2$V1 == df1$V1[i] & df1$V2[i] <= df2$V2 & df1$V3[i] > df2$V2
  sum <- sum(df2$V5[result])
  df1$V4[i] <- sum
}